# append same line of text to many text files

Tags: text, append

Windows 7 64 bit
I have many text files (.prm) that I would like to be able to simply add the same line of text to within each file either by cmd or batch.

### -For example:

```
Folder: PRM/
       Test_13_AABJ0053.prm
       Test_14_AABK0054_Shoulders.prm
       Test_15_AABK0054_Lung.prm
       Test_16_AABL0055.prm
       Test_17_AABM0056.prm
```

### Inside each file (example):Test_13_AABJ0053.prm

Scan 10 10 25
AABJ0053.inf

I would like to add the line: ADFilter_Strength 1
So it looks like this:
Scan 10 10 25
AABJ0053.inf
ADFilter_Strength 1

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using powershell from the folder:

`Get-ChildItem *.prm | % { echo "ADFilter_Strength 1" >> $_.pspath }`

Comment: installing PS wasn't something  I wanted to do on my company system- but I need to do my job!!  So I did and thanks this is great.  something new to learn- as I am quite green in cmd anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I have worked with this (***totalopinion***:evil) Operating system and my DOS is a little rusty but here goes:

for %f in (A*) do echo your-line >> "B\%~nxf"

Would love to test but not win box local ;)

Thanks,
//P

Comment: LOL yes very evil, indeed!!  unfortunately, I could not get this to work. But thank you, nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

The all-PS method is quite simple:

```
Get-ChildItem *.prm | Add-Content -Value "ADFilter_Strength 1"
```

Abbreviated:

```
gci *.prm | ac -va "ADFilter_Strength 1"
```